# Azure Devops OpenShift parallel release

Tags: azure-devops, openshift

We have containerized our .Net Core Web API using Docker and deploying to OpenShift

Below is the process we are following

Docker Image created
Image pushed to jfrog Artifactory from Azure Devops Build Pipeline

We have around 40 OpenShift Clusters where we have to deploy our App

Created Generic YAML template(references docker image with Tag_Name as Variable).
Created the template using OC commandline in all sites.

Now using Azure Devops Release pipeline we have created around 40 stages.
Each stage contains below tasks to trigger the templates

```
oc project $(project_name)
oc process template_name TAG_NAME="new_tag" | oc apply -f -
```

**Problem:**
If I need to deploy a new version of Docker Image(tag), running all the stages
takes lot of time. Is there any better way to run these stages parallel ?

With IIS deployments **we can make use of deployment groups**, but here in this case is there
a better way of doing it ?

I know that there is a way that if an image is pushed to artifactory all the clusters can
automatically pull that image, but I do not want in this way, I need more control over to
which set of clusters I am deploying.